# Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. For 2 separate naviagtions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following Navigation:

tabNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'

import HomeScreen from "../screens/homeScreen"
import SearchScreen from "../screens/searchScreen"
import MessagesScreen from "../screens/messagesScreen"
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/settingsScreen"
import EditProfileScreen from "../screens/editProfileScreen"

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();
const SettingsNavigator = () => (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} options={{ title: 'Edit Profile' }} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
)

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabNavigator = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)


export default TabNavigator
```

Im getting the following issues:

```
Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitely. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.
```

I have tried removing the `NavigationContainer` but this is not working.

I think I have narrowed it down to an issue with:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} />
```

Passing in `SettingsNavigator` into the tab. But not 100% sure.

Comment: do you have navigation set up in App.js or other file too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another `<NavigationContainer>` wrapper in my `App.js`.

Removing this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to make it a separate file Like that

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();
const SettingsNavigator = () => (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} options={{ title: 'Edit Profile' }} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
)
}
export default SettingsStack
```

======= Your Main Tab class here call your setting Navigator=======

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabNavigator = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)


export default TabNavigator
```

That will work.